# Can't find Blank app (XAML) in VS 2013 for win 8.1. where going to follow to guide from head first book to learn c#

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

Can't find Blank app (XAML) in VS 2013 for win 8.1. i where going to follow to guide from head first book to learn c#.

Answer (score 1):

It may be under a different name, especially if you're using a different update. Do File.New Project... then look under Visual C# / Store Apps / Universal Apps or Visual C# / Store Apps / Windows Apps

[image]